# Redirecting (301) from a shared htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I need to redirect individual pages (each page to its new equivalent) from a domain **[www.mysite.de](http://www.mysite.de)**
to a subdomain **de.mysite.com**. The htaccess file of the original site is shared with other domains (other languages).

In order to complicate more, I have to redirect also certain folders that can contain hundreds of pages each, to a single page in the new subdomain (for each one of the original folders). For example everything under **[www.mysite.de/folder1/](http://www.mysite.de/folder1/)** to **de.mysite.com/page1/**.

Any ideas that would also be practical for a large set of redirects?

Thanks.

Comment: Sure, the obvious idea is to 1. to redirect all pages to folders where you can use a common matching pattern and 2. to redirect all remaining individual pages one by one.

Comment: An alternate idea would be to use a redirection logic based on a map instead of using matching patterns.